# SVM regression with longitudinal data

Tags: regression, svm, panel-data

I have about 500 variables per patient, each variable has one continous value and is measured at three different time points (after 2 month and after 1 year). With the regression I would like to predict the treatment outcome for new patients.

Is it possible to use SVM regression with such longitudinal data?

Comment: Were you able to find any proper answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question and I did a quick research.

The OP asked about **regression** for continuous data. But the paper cited by @Vikram only works for **classification**.

> Lu, Z., Kaye, J., & Leen, T. K. (2009). Hierarchical Fisher Kernels
>   for Longitudinal Data. In *Advances in Neural Information Processing
>   Systems*.

A related paper for **regression** I found is [the following](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231211003389). Technical details can be found in Section 2.3.

> Seok, K. H., Shim, J., Cho, D., Noh, G. J., & Hwang, C. (2011).
>   Semiparametric mixed-effect least squares support vector machine for
>   analyzing pharmacokinetic and pharmacodynamic data. *Neurocomputing*,
>   74(17), 3412-3419.

No public software is found but the authors claimed the ease of use at the end of the paper.

> The main advantage of the proposed LS-SVM ... is that regression estimators
>   can be easily computed by softwares solving a simple linear
>   equation system. This makes it easier to apply the proposed
>   approach to the analysis of repeated measurement data in practice.

To elaborate a bit more, there are two approaches for **regression** analysis using [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (support vector machine):

- **support vector regression (SVR)** [Drucker, Harris; Burges, Christopher J. C.; Kaufman, Linda; Smola, Alexander J.; and Vapnik, Vladimir N. (1997); "Support Vector Regression Machines", in *Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems* 9, NIPS 1996, 155–161]
- **least squares support vector machine (LS-SVM)** [Suykens, Johan A. K.; Vandewalle, Joos P. L.; Least squares support vector machine classifiers, *Neural Processing Letters*, vol. 9, no. 3, Jun. 1999, pp. 293–300.]

The aforementioned Seol et al. (2011) adopted the [LS-VSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares_support_vector_machine) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Except that in longitudinal data using Fisher Kernel works better than RBF or Linear ones. A similar setting like that of yours is given in this NIPS paper: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/147234/NIPS08.pdf